# Excel VBA error 1004 when trying to set multiple PageSetup footer values

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use Excel-VBA to set the PageSetup information for my worksheet, but it is giving me the following error:

> Run-time error ‘1004’:
>
> Unable to set the LeftFooter property of the PageSetup class

The relevant example code follows:

```
Set WS = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

WS.DisplayPageBreaks = False
With WS.PageSetup
    .PrintArea = "$A$1:$L$32"
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .CenterHeader = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" & Chr(10) & _ 
                    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    .CenterFooter = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" & Chr(10) & _ 
                    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    .RightFooter = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" & Chr(10) & _ 
                   "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    .LeftFooter = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" & Chr(10) & _ 
                  "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" & Chr(10) & _ 
                  "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    .CenterHorizontally = True
    .Zoom = False
End With
```

Strangely, if I comment out any one of the three .xxxFooter lines, the code works fine. If I rearrange them into any possible different order, they all work with the exception of the last one which will throw the same 1004 error but for the new .xxxFooter.

This user seems to have a highly related problem, but did not ever resolve it: [Error when setting Worksheet.PageSetup.XxxFooter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105551/error-when-setting-worksheet-pagesetup-xxxfooter). As a comment to the questions there, yes, I do have a printer installed.

**Edit:**

Another discovery: if I remove some of the characters, then it will work again. Adding in additional characters manually eventually caused this error box to pop up:

> The text string you entered is too long. Reduce the number of characters used.

I can temporarily work around by abbreviating a lot of things in the footer, but is there any other way to solve this problem, and can anyone explain why there is a character limit in the footers? That seems arcane in Excel 2016...

Comment: Please copy/paste your actual code into the question - the currently posted code would give syntax errors due to all the smart-quotes in it

Comment: Also, `ActiveWorkbook` does not have an `ActiveWorksheet` property.  Are you **sure** your code is running?

Comment: What are you talking about? That is the actual code with the exception of the text lines are dynamically created. But they end up in that format... text,  carriage return, text. What smart-quotes?

Comment: Your posted code is showing `“$A$1:$L$32”` and `“Text line 1”` (for instance) instead of what I would expect, which would be `"$A$1:$L$32"` and `"Text line 1"`.  VBA treats `“` and `”` completely differently to how it treats `"`.

Comment: Yes, I assure you it runs. I have the sheet defined as a named sheet, so I put that as an example. I updated the syntax.

Comment: It is a string. I don't know how it is showing on SO, but it is a string, and I have tested them all with Debug.Print. All the code works if you comment out one of the three footer lines.

Comment: After fixing the code errors, the code works fine for me.  Does the actual posted code (after fixing the errors) crash for you, or is it only your "real" code that crashes.

Comment: Hmm... the above code works. The example strings are just a little shorter than the real ones though... is there a character limit with these properties?

Comment: Don't know about character limits (it's possible I guess) but we won't be able to provide much help if the only errors in the posted code is the syntax errors caused by the smart-quotes.  You may have to post something that will allow us to replicate the issue.

Comment: Actually, I just typed garbage into the various strings until they were fairly long and it crashed on setting `RightFooter` so, yes, it sounds like you have to ensure that the footers won't overlap each other.

Comment: The text was obfuscated for privacy, but I will update the example to have the same number of characters as the real problem. It's at work though, so I'll have to post the edit tomorrow. Syntax issues modified.

Comment: My guess is the maximum number of characters you will be able to use will be based on the printer you are printing to - I don't think it will be a fixed value.  (But that's just a guess based on how I **suspect** it would be processing it.)

Comment: No - it might be limited to 256 bytes over all the footer strings (including `Chr(10)`s obviously) and what might possibly be some control bytes used to separate the left / center / right. (E.g. with left and right empty, I could set center to 253 bytes.  But to put 1 byte in right, I first had to reduce center to 250 bytes.)

Comment: Edited to show the same number of characters as the real product.